# Do I need to call DeleteObject() on font retrieved from SystemParametersInfo()?

Tags: windows, winapi, memory-management, fonts

I'm getting system's default font like this:

```
NONCLIENTMETRICS ncm;
ncm.cbSize = sizeof(NONCLIENTMETRICS);
SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETNONCLIENTMETRICS, sizeof(NONCLIENTMETRICS), &ncm, 0);
HFONT hFont = CreateFontIndirect(&ncm.lfMessageFont);
```

then

chaging control's font like this:

```
SendMessage(hwnd, WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM) hFont, TRUE);
```

My question is, since this font was retrieved by [`SystemParametersInfo()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-systemparametersinfow), do I need to delete it with [`DeleteObject()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-deleteobject)? I'm not sure whatever the OS owns that memory so that I don't need to free it.

Comment: Please, your question is not about the C programming language.  Edit your question to take off the tag `C`, as your question is related to the use of a library, and not a question related to the programming language used.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I edited it for you.  My apologies if this is not what you want, but it attracts the attention of the wrong people to read it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`SystemParametersInfo` returns `LOGFONT` structures. Those structures do not need to be released.

Creating a font (from a `LOGFONT` or otherwise) makes you responsible for resource cleanup. The font object here wasn't created by `SystemParametersInfo`, but by the call to `CreateFontIndirect`.

Comment: You're right, the memory itself was returned by `CreateFontIndirect()` so it's the resources I must free, right?

Comment: Yes. That's explained in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-createfontindirectw), too.

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, you don't need to call `DeleteObject()` on a `LOGFONT` structure.

However, you will need to call `DeleteObject()` on the `HFONT` returned from `CreateFontIndirect()`.

BUT AN EVEN BIGGER HOWEVER, ... you need to wait to call `DeleteObject()` on the `HFONT` until you destroy the window (and any other window) you set the font to using `WM_SETFONT`.

Pseudo code:

1. Get your `NONCLIENTMETRICS`...
2. Call `hFont = CreateFontIndirect()`
3. Call `SendMessage(WM_SETFONT)`
4. Wait for window to be destroyed (or application cleanup)
5. Call `DeleteObject()` on `hFont`

If you are going to use the `HFONT` for multiple windows, create it once and then wait until application shutdown to clean it up (or, wait until a point you know that all the windows you used it with have been destroyed).

Comment: When `WM_DESTROY` messaged is received from main windows procedure, is the proper place to delete this font?

Comment: Yeah, should be safe. As long as that is the only window using the font. I usually use MFC so I do it in my destructor (which is after WM_DESTROY in normal usage).

Comment: You mean as long it's the last window using that font? I'm setting that font to all controls in the application, looping over them with `EnumChildWindows`, see full code https://pastebin.com/qbjNEXhT then calling `DeleteObject` where `WM_DESTROY` message is received from main windows procedure

Comment: Don't delete if it's not the last window using it. If it's the main window and every other window is a child, then it's safe. I can't see the code because my company's firewall is blocking pastebin

Comment: I see, it's the main window and every other window is a child. Blocking pastebin? that's odd...